# Scratch Image on PictureBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-processing, picturebox

I coded this to scratch image on picturebox.

```
bool draw = false;

int pX = -1;
int pY = -1;

Bitmap drawing;

public Form1()
{
    drawing = new Bitmap(transformedImage.Width, transformedImage.Height, transformedImage.CreateGraphics());
    Graphics.FromImage(drawing).Clear(Color.Transparent);
}

private void transformedImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draw)
        {
            int penWidth = Convert.ToInt32(penWidthValue.Value);
            if(blackCheck.Checked == true) ///black pen
            {
                Graphics panel = Graphics.FromImage(drawing);

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, penWidth);

                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

                panel.DrawLine(pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);

                transformedImage.CreateGraphics().DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));                    
            }
            else if(redCheck.Checked == true) /// red pen
            {
                Graphics panel = Graphics.FromImage(drawing);

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, penWidth);

                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

                panel.DrawLine(pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);

                transformedImage.CreateGraphics().DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));
            }
            else if(yellowCheck.Checked == true) /// yellow
            {
                Graphics panel = Graphics.FromImage(drawing);

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, penWidth);

                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

                panel.DrawLine(pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);

                transformedImage.CreateGraphics().DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));
            }
            else /// green
            {
                Graphics panel = Graphics.FromImage(drawing);

                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, penWidth);

                pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

                panel.DrawLine(pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);

                transformedImage.CreateGraphics().DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));
            }

        }

        pX = e.X;
        pY = e.Y;
    }

    private void transformedImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (scratchCheck.Checked == true)
        {
            draw = true;
            pX = e.X;
            pY = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void transformedImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = false;
    }

    private void transformedImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(drawing, new Point(0, 0));  
    }
```

But when I saved image using this:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.Title = "Select Save Location";
                sfd.InitialDirectory = @"Save_Path";
                sfd.AddExtension = true;
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    switch (Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName).ToUpper())
                    {
                        case ".BMP":
                            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                            break;
                        case ".gif":
                            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Gif);
                            break;
                        case ".JPG":
                            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            break;
                        case ".JPEG":
                            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            break;
                        case ".PNG":
                            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                            break;
                        case ".png":
                            bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

The image scratched on picturebox was not scratched.

This is scratched image on picturebox before saving:
[image]

But when I saved using above code, the scratches were gone missing:
[image]

How to saved the picture along with the scratches?, Thank you very much.

Comment: Small nitpick. In your switch statement (`Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName).ToUpper()`), you don't need to include the lowercase variations: `case ".gif":` as they'll never be hit.

Comment: We need to see more of the `SaveFileDialog()` code. (How are you calling it?)

Comment: I coded that SaveFileDialog() in the button that will save the image on the picturebox.

Comment: what is `bmp`??? Should it be `drawing`?? Also simplify your mouse move method. The only difference between each `if` statement is the PenColor. Couln't you easily change the if statements to only set the Pen instance then you only need one section to actually draw the scratch... See this example.. https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEQKzB

Comment: @FrankerZ Solved, I used the image variable to save it along with the scratches.

Answer (score 1):

Two common errors:

1. using `CreateGraphics` will not create **persistent** graphics. So: Alwas draw everything in the `Paint` event of the `PictureBox`! The `MouseMove` should only **collect** the points in a `List<Point>` or a `List<List<Point>>`. **All** drawing **must** happen in the `Paint` event using its `e.Graphics` object!
2. The drawing on the surface only gets saved if you use `DrawToBitmap` to create a new bitmap, which will combine up to **three layers**: the `BackgroundImage`, the `Image` and all **persistent** drawings.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988079/copying-free-hand-drawing-from-panel-in-visual-studio-2013/32112426#32112426) for an example of drawing and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848324/fill-picturebox-with-multiple-images-and-save-it-c-sharp/33854928#33854928) for an example of using `DrawToBitmap`!

As an alternative to this recommended way of drawing over an `Image` you can also draw directly into it. This is what are actually doing in the `MouseMove`, but later you ignore the image and draw it in a non-persistent way.

Finally: The `Save` routine is saving a `bmp` whichyou have not shown us, so we can only conclude that it is the original `Image` you loaded.. Maybe `drawing.Save(..)` would help..

But there are so many issues with the code, that you really should do a complete rewrite, starting with the confusing names! (Hint: do not call an object the name of a different type, like `Graphics panel`!!!) And obviously a variable of type `Pen` or `Color` would also help avoiding those repetitions...